# Potentiallly dangerous request.form value detected

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to insert the record into table through web page.Dropdownlist contain '<'.Because of that I am getting an error.Error is 'Potentiallly dangerous request.form value detected.'.I searched on the net.I got the solution which is working perfectly.But I did not understand exact meaning of it.

Following line disable the validation of requests for the page
`Soln: ValidateRequest = "false"` at page level.I am using 4.5 framework.so I added `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode = "2.0" />.`

What is exact meaning of httpRuntime requestValidationMode.Does it affect my other pages?

Comment: I don't think your question title and your actual question are very related.

Comment: Look at the values in your drop down list.  My guess is that you have some unintended values such as HTML or JQuery.  Turning off the ValidationRequest is a bad thing to do.  It help to protect against things like cross scripting.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode.aspx

> 2.0. Request validation is enabled only for pages, not for all HTTP requests. In addition, the request validation settings of the pages
>   element (if any) in the configuration file or of the @ Page directive
>   in an individual page are used to determine which page requests to
>   validate.

It affects all pages, but if you want you can change behaviour for specific pages

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to encode the value to HTML before adding in your DropDownList ?

Because the validateRequest process check that you don't try to send potentially dangerous code like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>Delete all my famous code</script>
```

By if you encode this code it's not potential dangerous code because it can't be interpreted but just display on the page.